# Personalized protected frontend content on a "per User" base in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

For a current project i need to provide some of the client's clients (you go it? =) some kind of protected frontend content area. This area should hold protected content on a "per User"-base.

**For example:** Tom from (lets call the company EXCORP) wants to provide **User A** with a document (PDF) and some Text (HTML-Content). But(!) **User B** would get a totally different document and maybe some more Text. **User C** would possibly not get a document at all.

This Game goes on for circa another 150 users or so. So going by "default" roles doesn't work here, since i would have to create one user-role per user and that would definitely overkill it. And all the Membership Plugins i've found do not work that way.

Just to make that clear: This thing only goes one way. Meaning, Client-Supporter Tom (in example above) needs to provide all the clients some personalised information. Tom would be a Backend-User. Clients do not need to provide eachother some files or information. Just from one Backend-User to all the different Frontend-Users.

So my question clearly spoken: **Is there a way to protect frontend content on a "per User"-base using Wordpress?** It doesn't matter to me if I get it to work the "hacky" way, or by a premium/free plugin, as long as it is safe (I will use SSL of course). I just don't want to develop a plugin from scratch, though my client would never speak the budget to pay for it!

Comment: how are you deciding what content to show to which user? on the basis of user id ?

Comment: @wordpresser yes, that could be one way. Though i didn't really consider the technical issues yet. I would have to do that if i don't find a already working solution. Fact is: every single user would/should have his/hers completely personalized page(s).

Comment: you mean as per your example User A will have same authority as Tom, i.e to publish some text and docs and decide who gonna see what .. ?

Comment: @wordpresser No, sorry if I was unclear. This thing only goes one way. Meaning, Client-Supporter Tom (in example above) needs to provide all the clients some personalised information. Tom would be a Backend-User. Clients do not need to provide eachother some files or information. Just from one Backend-User to all the different Frontend-Users.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of themes outhere that offer front end user dashboard, you can use one of thoes themes to have everything set up (user redirected to his/hers dashboard at login).

At this point you have many ways to acchive what you need, if it's not too much trobule to remember what user received what info you can simply add a user-box in post-creation/edit backend where Tom can create a post, attach files to it and asign it to another user(throw the user box).

Publishing the post as private and changing the author from Tom to the end-user should make your work much more easier.

P.S. Check classifieds themes to see how backend works the main difference between thoes and what you'll have to achieve is that the post is craeted by Tom but asigned to the user (very easy to do) and that the post MUST BE PRIVATE!!! don't forget this if the data is sensible!

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but thought this might help others. You could try using [wp-document-revisions](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-document-revisions/) along with the [members plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/) to achieve what you are looking for.

Good luck.